# R check warning: Files in the 'vignettes' directory but no files in 'inst/doc'

Tags: r, cran, r-package

Lately I get a warning for my vignette on Win R Development Version when doing a cran check.

> Files in the 'vignettes' directory but no files in 'inst/doc'

This warning only appears with the Win Dev version.
For Mac, AppVeyor and Travis no warning appears.

The problem is, I don't know what the warning wants to tell me.
As far as I know I do not have to put files in inst/doc.

Here is the complete warning message:

```
Files in the 'vignettes' directory but no files in 'inst/doc':
'Figures.d/Rlogo.png', 'Figures.d/distribution.pdf',
'Figures.d/distributionbar.pdf', 'Figures.d/gapsize.pdf',
'Figures.d/imputations.pdf', 'Figures.d/imputations2.pdf',
'Figures.d/sponsorlogo.jpg', 'Figures.d/statsna.png',
'Figures.d/tsairgap.png', 'Introduction.pdf', 'Introduction.tex',
'RJournal.sty'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem with adding the .pdf output of my Vignette to inst/doc

Although I am not sure, if this is the supposed solution, it made the warning disappear.

Comment: yes! copying the pdf output to a folder inside the inst folder worked for me. I wonder why it doesn't happen automatically if it is a required step.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was getting this issue because I had specified my YAML as per @Claudia's answer, but I had specified `rmarkdown` as the VignetteBuilder in the DESCRIPTION file. Using `VignetteBuilder: knitr` in my DESCRIPTION file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with an Rmd vignette. I fixed it by changing the YAML header of the vignette to something like this:

```
---
author: "Name Surname"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Title of your vignette}
  %\usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc}
---
```

Comment: In http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html the line `%\usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc}` doesn't contain the `%` at the beginning: ` \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, (I use it this way)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error on more than just the Win R Development version, but for me the fix was adding `markdown` and `knitr` in the `Suggests` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file. Then, I guess it was clear to the package compiler that the vignette was designated as a markdown/HTML doc.
These lines are in my markdown YAML header:

```
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Example for estimating the case fatality ratio}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 0):

`usethis::use_vignette()` for vignette creation will take care of this.

Answer (score -1):

During the compiling of your R package, those files are generated and cause your issue.
You should install the package gitignore, then in the main folder you have to create a text file named ".gitignore" (no extension) and add the address of the files you want to ignore. For example, vignettes/*.pdf

Comment: I do not think this is related because the building of R packages is independent of the workings of git. Maybe you meant .Rbuildignore, but that is not helpful here either.