# Making R package vignettes discoverable by browseVignettes

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package, vignette

I'm using Rstudio and devtools to build vignettes for an R packge.

All vignettes are in the `/vignettes` directory. However, when I run `R CMD check` I get a warning:

```
> checking files in 'vignettes' ... WARNING
  Files in the 'vignettes' directory but no files in 'inst/doc':
    'my_package_vignette.Rmd'
```

I can use `devtools::build_vignettes()` to build each vignette, but it does not create a copy of the vignette in `inst/doc`, where I understand `browseVignettes("my.package")` will look.

I would like my vignettes to be discoverable by `browseVignettes("my.package").

I found this issue, and [this "solution"](https://community.rstudio.com/t/browsevignettes-mypackage-saying-no-vignettes-found/68656/7):

```
tools::buildVignettes(dir = ".", tangle=TRUE)
dir.create("inst/doc")
file.copy(dir("vignettes", full.names=TRUE), "inst/doc", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, when I run `R CMD check` in Rstudio, it erases the `inst/doc` directory.

I have seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670800/r-check-warning-files-in-the-vignettes-directory-but-no-files-in-inst-doc), but none of the solutions resolve my question.

How do I build package vignettes in Rstudio so that they are discoverable by `browseVignettes()`?

Comment: In the past I've had success using `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: @dario I've read that elsewhere, and it may have worked in the past, but as of right now that isn't building vignettes into the `inst/doc` directory.